# Ad is not appear

Tags: android, admob

I would like to run an google developers example app which I have got from 
[here](http://google-mobile-dev.googlecode.com/files/Android_XML.zip)

1. I have registred at admobs.com from where I have my Ad unit ID which is in form: ca-app-pub-7.../... In main.xml I have then replaced AD_UNIT_ID_GOES_HERE for this new Ad unit ID.
2. Then I have replaced in main.xml TEST_DEVICE_ID_GOES_HERE for device id I have got from logcat:

   ```
   09-07 19:49:30.881: I/Ads(5735): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice("EFEA76C9D061FDD37B8ABF6EB712A991");
   ```

Also in BannerSample.java I have add code into onCreate:

```
package com.google.example.ads.xml;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
* A simple {@link Activity} which embeds an AdView in its layout XML.
*/
public class BannerSample extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // This example requires no additional code since the optional
    // "loadAdOnCreate=true" XML attribute was used. If "loadAdOnCreate" were
    // not specified, the ad would have to be loaded by creating an AdRequest
    // and using Activity.findViewById() to get the AdView.
    //
    // The "loadAdOnCreate" XML attribute makes it simpler to get ads since no
    // code is required, but it also limits the developer's control over the ad
    // request since a generic AdRequest is used.

    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
    request.addTestDevice("EFEA76C9D061FDD37B8ABF6EB712A991");

  }
}
```

I waited few minutes and App was running but ads banner is not appear.

Logcat:

```
09-07 20:32:01.037: W/webcore(5945): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
09-07 20:33:00.306: I/Ads(5945): AdLoader timed out after 60000ms while getting the URL.
09-07 20:33:00.310: D/webviewglue(5945): nativeDestroy view: 0x1cb198
09-07 20:33:00.322: I/Ads(5945): onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred.)
```

I have I also tried already add code to manifest.(I have seen it there on stackoverflow but didn't worked).

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID"
        android:value="pub-7..."
        >
    </meta-data>
```

I am using latest version GoogleAdMobAdsSdkAndroid-6.4.1. Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT:
I have tried my app on emulator and other phone and there was no problem. Ad banner was showing fine. Phone where banner isn't appearing is Samsung I5801 with android 2.3.7. It is not my phone originally and it is probably rooted phone what could be reason, but I am not sure(I have found it on forum).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

in Main Layout add 
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
and

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="YOUR_KEY"
    ads:refreshInterval="32" />
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can define your admob id in a string, along with all test devices for easy access

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:googleads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/myAdView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    googleads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    googleads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id"
    googleads:testDevices="@string/ADS_TEST_DEVICES" />
```

Then in your activity:

```
package com.google.example.ads.xml;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
* A simple {@link Activity} which embeds an AdView in its layout XML.
*/
public class BannerSample extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    AdView myAdView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.myAdView);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    myAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
  }
}
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

You may forget to Add permissions on your Android maifest file. Seems like that

INTERNET and 
ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permissions are required in your Android manifest closer to your manifest tag.

Answer (score 0):

The message: `There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 1` reffers that the  ad unit ID is invalid.

```
public static final int ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST
The ad request was invalid; for instance, the ad unit ID was incorrect.
Constant Value: 1 (0x00000001)
```

The solution is changing the `ad unit ID`.